# SAPUI5 - How do I disable text input in DateRangeSelection

Tags: datepicker, sapui5, date-range

I need to completely disable text entry on a DateRangeSelection, so that only the calendar selection can be accepted..

I can the disable text input for a DatePicker component with...

```
view.byId("__reportDate")._bMobile = true;
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for a DateRangeSelection.

Is there anything else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

There does not seem to be a standard property to do it, you can however tweak the underlying input element used to set it to readonly. This would disable any text input in the field. This might be one of the ways to do it.

```
var oDateSel = this.getView().byId("dateSel");
$("#"+oDateSel.sId+" input").prop("readonly",true);
```

Note: **This is certainly not a standard approach according to the UI5 standards**. Also you might have to set a handler to set the element to readonly if the control is re-rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was...

```
 var dateSel = sap.ui.getCore().byId("dateRange");
 $("#"+dateSel.sId+" input").prop("disabled",true);
```

(readonly wiped out the placeholder in IE).